# Data not showing on Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been following  [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio) on how to use Google Firebase. I've been following the code and because I kept seeing:

> **Error:** No resource found that matches the given name (at 'paddingBottom' with value '@dimen/ activity_vertical_margin')

I added a few lines to app/srs/main/res/values/dimens so it now looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">5dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

I'm trying to add items to the database but I can't seem to end the file by clicking the button. Consequently, no data is showing up on Firebase. Cheers!

[image: Screenshot of emulator running app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please recheck once:

1) Go to Firebase console, select Database.

2) Selecte Rules.

paste below one:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
}
```

Your Activity should be:

```
 public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (edittext.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("myref").push().setValue(edittext.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and your_activity.xml will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Item"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to give margin at xml like this:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />
```

**Note** this will solve the error which you mention above .
Hope this will help you out..and let me
 know your feedback